# Flutter How can we convert Uint8List image to .jpg / .png?

Tags: flutter

I am using `flutter_inappwebview` to take screenshot of the webpage. The screenshot in is `Uint8List` format. I want to change it into `File` so that I can save it in my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() is from path_provider package.

onPressed: () async {
          final result = await webView.takeScreenshot();
          final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path; // to get path of the file
          String fileName = DateTime.now().toIso8601String(); // the name needs to be unique every time you take a screenshot
          var path = '$directory/$fileName.png';

          File image = await File(path).writeAsBytes(result); // thanks to the answer above by @Guillaume Roux

           showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                content: Image.file(image),
              );
            },
          );
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with `path` being the full path to your image and `img` your `Uint8List`:

```dart
File newFile = await File(path).writeAsBytes(img);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I have written the complete solution below. Without your help it would not have been possible. Thank once again.